# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' for only KNN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, traceback

I am trying to develop Logistic Regression, KNN, Support Vector Classifier and Random Forrest classifiers for something. I have been able to get everything to work except for the KNN. The code for the KNN is below.

```
# knn tuning
grid = {'n_neighbors': [1,3,5,7,9,11]}
knn_mod = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsRegressor(), grid, cv=5)
knn_mod.fit(x_train, y_train) 
knn_mod.best_estimator_ 
print(knn_mod.best_params_)
```

The traceback error says something is wrong with the knn_mod.fit line of code. Not sure what is causing it since I use essentially the same code/formatting for the other three models that work. Any tips/suggestions for how I can fix this problem?

Comment: PLease attach the complete error code

Comment: Also what does the data in `x_train` and `y_train` look like?

Comment: It must be an error with `x_train` or `y_train`. Please add the first five observations of each.